# Cannot open port 8153 on amazon ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, port

I am trying the free tier on amazon ec2 and have a red hat 64bit instance set up with Go Server running on port 8153.
I disabled IPTables and switched SELINUX to permissive and then added 8153 to amazon security policy and restarted the instance. However when I try to access the port on my browser outside of the instance I cant connect. The port is open according to netstat and nmap and when I run curl command on the instance it works.

Is this a problem with free tier instances?

EDIT: Weird thing is if I install a web server like nginx on it and open port 80 on security policy I can access it fine on any browser but not anything apart from web server. Even installed tomcat and cant access it either.

Comment: are you able to `telnet` to port 8153 ?

Comment: hi no cant telnet from outside the instance.

Comment: are you sure that you have that port access allowed in AWS Security group? Also can you provide output of `netstat -anp | grep 8153`

Comment: Yes I am very sure I have allowed 8153 in security group. netstat command shows  tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8153                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1782/java

Comment: what is the IP address you have allowed access for port 8153 in your AWS SEcurity group? THis is mostly issue with security group configuration

Comment: I have allowed all IPs so 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a corporate firewall.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the output of `iptables-save` ? Without rebooting the instances. Also did you open tcp port 8153 to 0.0.0.0/0 on your security groups?  How did you disable iptables on the instances, maybe after reboot they got re-enabled?

Comment: iptables.save contains this 

-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8153  -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 8154 -j ACCEPT
ith icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT

Comment: Yes port 8153 open to 0.0.0.0 and I always use "sudo iptables stop" when rebooting instance. so its always off

Comment: Just like  slayedbylucifer said, it's got to be a problem with the way  security groups are set for the instance.

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with it though. I am allowing all IPs through and port number is correct and its attached to the correct instance. This makes no sense at all as with iptables off there should be nothing blocking access.

Comment: Another thing to look at is where are you connecting from ? Could it be that your firewall may be blocking port 8153 ?

Comment: Nope no firewall blocking that port. if I run go server locally I can connect fine. Tried 3 different locations.

Comment: How about running your app on another port, other than 8153 ? Don't know if it has anything to do with this: http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8153